# 555 to debounce comparator output for PIR circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, 555, debounce

I'm trying to create a circuit that takes an input from a PIR and outputs a high signal when movement is detected. My circuit currently looks like the schematic below (VCC is 5V).

[image]

The circuit works and the output goes high when movement is detected however it oscillates (it also only goes from 1.6V to 3.4V rather than 0V to 5V but I don't think this is a big issue - simple transistor would fix I think). I have shown this in the sketch below.

[image]

I would like to condition the signal more so that I can put it into an interrupt on my microcontroller to count the number of seperate movements detected (the aim is to count people through a door way, maybe one person every couple of seconds).

I could do this in code by:

- Countdown = maximum possible bounce time.
- Input from PIR sensor circuit is normally low.
- When input from PIR sensor goes high it starts a countdown or resets currently running countdown.
- If countdown reaches 0 we have 1 detection.

However I would prefer do do it in hardware so I was thinking that a watchdog timer built around a 555 does a very similar job. Something like:

- Countdown = maximum possible bounce time.
- Watchdog output is normally low.
- Input from PIR sensor circuit is normally low.
- When the input from PIR sensor goes high (start watchdog + kick) the watchdog output goes high and starts a countdown (charging a cap).
- Every time the input from PIR sensor goes high either: if countdown has not finished (kick) which restarts the countdown (output stays high) or if countdown has finished start watchdog + kick.
- When countdown has ended the output goes low (stop watchdog).

QUESTIONS

- I know I would need to calculate the correct resistor and cap values but I wanted to know if this is feasible first?
- Can anyone give me a quick diagram of how this would be connected up?
- If a watchdog circuit is not the right solution what other circuits would you recommend?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to write down at the highest level, what pattern of high and low would you consider a movement to be counted. What would not count. When would you consider it two, three? Then try to implement that in software... why add extra analog parts when you can invent an algorithm and do it all in the microcontroller?

Comment: The general software debounce rule is very simple: don't poll faster than the maximum debounce period. This implies that you cannot detect actions that are shorter than the debounce period (at elast not without extra knowledge).

Comment: "However I would prefer do do it in hardware" - Sounds like you need a re-triggerable monostable circuit - easily done with a 555

Comment: The high low pattern is completely random depending on the amount of motion detected and the length of time the motion is detected for, however the maximum low time is known. If the signal goes low for more than this maximum low time then I will count it as the end of one detection. I don't want to do it on a microcontroller because I'm worried the signal might go high again before the interrupt from the first high has finished being handled. I don't want to poll slowly because I might miss 2 detection's or double count. The re-triggerable monostable circuit looks like it will work. Thanks

Comment: I will try the circuit tomorrow and come back with an answer or probably more questions.